# Agregar estilo a Chechbox

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes estoy intentando cambiar de color al checkbox pero no lo he logrado

```
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
```

he encontrado mediante css lo siguiente

```
  input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
display: none;
}
label:before {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
width: 1.25em;
display: inline-block;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before  {
content: "f10c";
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
content: "f111"; 
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
content: "f096"; 
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
content: "f046";
}
```

Pero yo solo quiero cambiarle el color al borde y al circulo del centro, he probado de todo pero aun no consigo como realizarlo, espero me ayuden...

Comment: para cosas tipo UI, front end... yo suelo usar bibliotecas con una cierta funcionalidad, he usado bootstrap, pero creo que es de pago, ahora voy a empezar con xf, puedes adquirir el paquete nuget de esta ultima, y a ver si por ahi tirando puedes hacer algo

Answer (score 0):

Googleando un poco he encontrado lo siguiente: `border:1px solid #1e5180` sin embargo en Firefox no funciona muy bien o eso pone en la referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css.
La sugerencia admitida como respuesta afirma que te programes algo en Javascript, hay otras respuestas que dicen que uses algo como `outline: 1px solid #1e5180`